# Teechart + Multiple Box Plots

Tags: activex, teechart

I need to plot around 80 Box Plot in Single chart, I have created 80Series with 7 Point eachs, The Issue is the Box plot are plotted properly since I am using Position but the problem is on X axis I am getting only 7 points labels I want that for all the 80 Box Plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a simple code that I think you can use to achieve as you want:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
TChart1.Aspect.View3D = False
TChart1.Legend.Visible = False
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To 80
TChart1.AddSeries scBox
TChart1.Series(i).FillSampleValues 7
TChart1.Series(i).asBoxPlot.Position = i + 10
Next
TChart1.Axis.Bottom.Labels.Style = talValue
TChart1.Axis.Bottom.Labels.Angle = 90
End Sub
```

Could you tell us if previous code help you? If it doesn't help please, tell us exactly what you want, so, we will try to give you, a good solution.

Thanks,

Comment: Actually I want to provide a label for each point on X-axis but I am not able to do that. I am getting Points values that to for only 7 points

Comment: @AkshayBhalla TeeChart tries to plot as many labels as can be fitted in an axis provided they don't overlap. You can try forcing this by setting axis Increment property although TeeChart won't let labels to overlap for aesthetic purposes. If you still want to force labels to be painted for each point you need to use custom axis labels. You'll find an example at All Features\Welcome\Axes\Labels\Custom Labels in the features demo available at TeeChart's program group.

Comment: There is another Issue here now when I try to add data table tool for 80 Box Plots it is not showing the table on the chart Window